# How to configure Eclipse to automatically insert import statements for classes with a single package match

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to configure Eclipse so that it automatically inserts an import statement whenever a class name has just one package match ?

Note: "Preferences/Java/Editor/Content Assist/Insert single proposals automatically" is turned on

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Bala R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273200/bala-r) commented, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> *(Organize Imports)* is the way to go.

*"Insert single proposals automatically"* is only for content assist - e.g. code completion.